# how to select the option value of a select tag?

Tags: php

how to select the option value of a select tag, by reading it from a text file, below is my code,

text file:txt.txt

```
  SUBMISSION TYPE:PRIORITY
```

php:

```
  $filename = 'txt.txt';
  $str = file_get_contents($filename);

   $data = explode("\n", $str);  

   for ($z=0; $z<=1; $z++){
     $data[$z] = explode(":", $data[$z]);
       }
   for ($y=0; $y<=1;$y++){
   if($data[$y][0]=="SUBMISSION TYPE"){
   $submissiontype= $data[$y][1];} 
    }
```

HTML:

```
     <th>Submission Type: <title="Submission Type"></th>

  <td><select id="submission" name="submission" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="NORMAL"<?php echo strcmp($submissiontype, 'NORMAL') === 0 ? ' selected' : ''; ?> >NORMAL</option>
 <option value="PRIORITY"<?php echo strcmp($submissiontype, 'PRIORITY') === 0 ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>PRIORITY</option>
 <option value="PAPERSTUDY"<?php echo strcmp($submissiontype, 'PAPERSTUDY') === 0 ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>PAPERSTUDY</option>
     </td>
```

Can anyone point out the mistake in this code ?

the HTML embedded PHP part of the code is not working, the submission type value is being selected as NORMAL always, even when i give it as PRIORITY.

Comment: what part of the code is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong here, but I think the problem is that `$data[$y][0] == "PROJECT TITLE"` is never true, so `$submissiontype` remains undefined and therefore the option that *should* be selected never is.

Shouldn't you be comparing `$data[$y][0]` to `"SUBMISSION TYPE"`?